# Aggregate results based on array of strings in JSON?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a field called 'keywords'. It is a JSONB field with an array of keyword metadata, including the keyword's name.

What I would like is to query the counts of all these keywords by name, i.e. aggregate on keyword name and `count(id)`. All the examples of GROUP BY queries I can find just result in the grouping occuring on the full list (i.e. only giving me counts where the two records have the same set of keywords).

So is it possible to somehow expand the list of keywords in a way that lets me get these counts?

If not, I am still at the planning stage and could refactor my schema to better handle this.

```
  "keywords": [
    {
      "addedAt": "2017-04-07T21:11:00+0000",
      "addedBy": {
        "email": "foo@bar.com"
      },
      "keyword": {
        "name": "Animal"
      }
    },
    {
      "addedAt": "2017-04-07T20:54:00+0000",
      "addedBy": {
        "email": "foo@bar.comm"
      },
      "keyword": {
        "name": "Mammal"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=442417e02cf08af527d5df1abe5f80f6)

```
SELECT
    elems -> 'keyword' ->> 'name' AS keyword,             -- 2
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    mytable t,
    jsonb_array_elements(myjson -> 'keywords') AS elems   -- 1
GROUP BY 1                                                -- 3
```

1. Expand the array records into one row per element
2. Get the keyword's names
3. Group these text values.

Comment: @deed02392 Did this help? In case, please do not forget to upvote and accept